# Python: rename all files in a folder using numbers that file contain

Tags: python

I want to write a little script for managing a bunch of files I got. Those files have complex and different name but they all contain a number somewhere in their name. I want to take that number, place it in front of the file name so they can be listed logically in my filesystem.

I got a *list* of all those files using os.listdir but I'm struggling to find a way to locate the numbers in those files. I've checked regular expression but I'm unsure if it's the right way to do this!

example:

```
import os
files = os.litdir(c:\\folder)
files
['xyz3.txt' , '2xyz.txt', 'x1yz.txt']`
```

So basically, what I ultimately want is:

```
1xyz.txt
2xyz.txt
3xyz.txt
```

where I am stuck so far is to find those numbers (1,2,3) in the list *files*

Comment: Show what you've got so far. Include both your regular expression and some example file names that you're trying to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (untested) snippet should show the regexp approach. The `search` method of compiled patterns is used to look for the number. If found, the number is moved to the front of the file name.

```
import os, re

NUM_RE = re.compile(r'\d+')

for name in os.listdir('.'):
    match = NUM_RE.search(name)
    if match is None or match.start() == 0:
        continue  # no number or number already at start
    newname = match.group(0) + name[:match.start()] + name[match.end():]
    print 'renaming', name, 'to', newname
    #os.rename(name, newname)
```

If this code is used in production and not as homework assignment, a useful improvement would be to parse `match.group(0)` as an integer and format it to include a number of leading zeros. That way `foo2.txt` would become `02foo.txt` and get sorted before `12bar.txt`. Implementing this is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers in your file names are integers (untested code):

```
def rename(dirpath, filename):
    inds = [i for i,char in filename if char in '1234567890']
    ints = filename[min(inds):max(inds)+1]
    newname = ints + filename[:min(inds)] + filename[max(inds)+1:]
    os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dirpath, newname))

def renameFilesInDir(dirpath):
    """ Apply your renaming scheme to all files in the directory specified by dirpath """

    dirpath, dirnames, filenames = os.walk(dirpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        rename(dirpath, filename)
    for dirname in dirnames:
        renameFilesInDir(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
```

Hope this helps